# Missing GO in sql file

Tags: sql, eclipse, encoding

I have a java application that builds and executes an sql statement/string. When I run the application from eclipse everything works fine.

But when I run the deployed/binary application (where .sql resources are read from binaries) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing sql:
..
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
```

I have tried to write the sql string to a file when running from eclipse and when running the deployed application. The two files are almost identical besides these small differences:

1) The working string starts with: 'go'

2) The working string has 'go' before IF

Any ideas why the source version has these tags while the build version does not? I build with gradle and set the compiler to use UTF-8:

```
[project.compileJava, project.compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

This is how I read the files from the jar file:

```
  InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
  String string = writer.toString();
```

Comment: you are linking to different libraries inside eclipse..??

Comment: huh? In the one case I run everything from source. In the other case I basically run an executable jar which has some other jars (containing the file resources) as dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `go` is not an SQL commando, it's a commando in eclipse. It's used to separate query batches.

To run the queries in SQL, remove the `go` commands (if possible without changing the result), or split the file on the `go` commands and run one batch at a time.

Comment: I have now tried to add "\ngo\n" + string to the jar code and it works again.